# React Setting State to Scope of Item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to learn React and build a simple application that pulls from the Reddit API. What I am trying to do now is to add a dummy star button that starts out empty with a border and when clicked is filled, like the user was able to like the post. I set a state for the start to false initially and when the user clicks the start the state is set to true and switch the styles of the star. My issue right now is when that is clicked it is doing what I want it to do, but is changing the style of the star for every post and not just the one post it was clicked for. So what I'm trying to do is keep the state in scope to the post item the star was clicked it. This is what my code looks like currently:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Card.css';

import axios from 'axios';
import SortControls from './SortControls/SortControls';

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

import { faStar as faStarRegular } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { faStar as faStarSolid } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(
  faStarRegular,
  faStarSolid
)
class Card extends React.Component {
    state = {
        news: [],
        starActive: false,
    };


componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/hot.json`).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({news: res.data.data.children});
    })
}

render() {


    return (
        <div className="container">
        <SortControls />
        <div className="cards">
            {this.state.news.map((newsItems, i) =>
           <div key={newsItems.data.id} className="card">
           <div className="cardHead"><h3>{newsItems.data.title}</h3></div>
           <div className="cardFooter">
                <div className="cardFooter__container">
                    <a href="#">View</a>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => this.setState({starActive: !this.state.starActive})} icon={ this.state.starActive ? ['fas', 'star'] : ['far', 'star'] } />

                </div>
            </div>
           </div>)}
        </div>
        </div>

    )
}

}


export default Card;
```

You can see my onClick and style change on the FontAwesomeIcon component.

So did I set this up wrong to keep the state in scope or is there just something I am missing to only update one star at a time on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

* *I will prefer the second one, because it would not rerender the whole news list, when you click on a single item.*

#### 1. When you click on a `<FontAwesomeIcon />` to keep the clicked newsItems ids in the state.

```
this.toggleId(id) {
  const { activeIds } = this.state

  if (activeIds.includes(activeIds)) {
    return this.setState({ activeIds: activeIds.filter(i => i !== id) })
  }

  this.setState({ activeIds: [...activeIds, id] })
}

// Render method ...
const { activeIds } = this.state

<FontAwesomeIcon
  onClick={() => this.toggleId(newsItems.data.id)}
  icon={ activeIds.includes(newsItems.data.id) ? ['fas', 'star'] : ['far', 'star'] } />
```

#### 2. Instead of keeping all clicked ids in `<Card />`, convert each news item as a single `<NewsItem />` component.

Having a single component, you can apply the same logic as your code example. Therefore the `starActive` flag will affect only the single component.

Something like that:

```
// Cards render
<div className="cards">
  { this.state.news.map((newsItem, i) => (
    <NewsItem {...newsItem} key={newsItem.data.id}  />
  ))}
</div>

// NewsItem
class NewsItem extends React.Component {
  state = {
    starActive: false,
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props

    return <div key={data.id} className="card">
      <div className="cardHead"><h3>{data.title}</h3></div>
        <div className="cardFooter">
          <div className="cardFooter__container">
             <a href="#">View</a>
             <FontAwesomeIcon
               onClick={() => this.setState({
                 starActive: !this.state.starActive
               })}
               icon={ this.state.starActive ? ['fas', 'star'] : ['far', 'star'] } />
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: i prefer second method to keep states separate

Comment: Awesome that worked perfectly! I went with option 2 to keep things more separated. Thanks for the help!